# How do I view all files of a repository in GitHub on a given commit version?

Tags: github

How can I switch to a commit ID in a way so that I not only see the changes, but I can view all files in the repository at that point in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the commit ID into the URL like this (without the square brackets):
[https://github.yourcompany.com/[organization]/[repository]/tree/[commit_id]](https://github.yourcompany.com/%5Borganization%5D/%5Brepository%5D/tree/%5Bcommit_id%5D)

In case of a specific file, it would be for example:
[https://github.yourcompany.com/[organization]/[repository]/blob/[commit_id]/.folder/Example.kt](https://github.yourcompany.com/%5Borganization%5D/%5Brepository%5D/blob/%5Bcommit_id%5D/.folder/Example.kt)